# C++ - Copy Assignment Operator in Template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to overload a copy assignment operator in template struct `xpair`

```
template <typename First, typename Second>
struct xpair {
   First first{};
   Second second{};

   xpair(){}
   xpair (const First& first, const Second& second):
           first(first), second(second) {}


   xpair& operator= (const xpair& that) {
      cout << "*this = " << *this << "      " << "that = " << that << endl;
      cout << "use operator = " << endl;
      *this = that;
      return *this;
   }
};
```

But when I test this code with

```
using commend = string;
using str_str_pair = xpair<string, string>;
using commend_pair = xpair<commend, str_str_pair>;

commend_pair cmd_pair;
str_str_pair str_pair("a", "1");
commend cmd("comment");

cmd_pair.first = cmd;
cmd_pair.second = str_pair;
```

It gives me infinite output as

```
use operator = 
*this = {,}      that = {a,1}
use operator = 
*this = {,}      that = {a,1}
use operator = 
*this = {,}      that = {a,1}
use operator = 
*this = {,}      that = {a,1}
```

Why is that?

Comment: You implemented a function as itself. There's a description of how that works in the first comment of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35282846).

Comment: You could remove this operator entirely and let the default `operator=` do its job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It gives me infinite output as
>   
>   Why is that?

Because you've defined the function in terms of itself, see the following code comment.

```
xpair& operator= (const xpair& that)
{
    cout << "*this = " << *this << "      " << "that = " << that << endl;
    cout << "use operator = " << endl;

    // Here you're asking for `this` (i.e., an `xpair` type) to be assigned
    // a `that` (i.e., another `xpair` type) using the `operator=` which is
    // the function currently being implemented/defined. A function calling
    // itself is recursion and there is no stopping condition so it will
    // continue infinitely.
    *this = that;
    return *this;
}
```

Instead your operation should set the data members of `this` instance using the data members of `that` instance.

```
xpair& operator= (const xpair& that)
{
    cout << "*this = " << *this << "      " << "that = " << that << endl;
    cout << "use operator = " << endl;

    first = that.first;
    second = that.second;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
  *this = that;
```

is an assignment as well, taking two arguments. And both are `xpair<First,Second>`, so it calls the same operator again.

What you would probably like to do is this:

```
this->first = that.first;
this->second = that.second;
```

which calls the assignment operators for `First` and `Second`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, as others have noted, that your `operator=` calls your `operator=`.  This results in an infinite recursion.

But, I'll argue for a different implementation:

Add this:

```
template<class Self,
  class=std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<Self>, xpair>{}>
>
friend auto tieme(Self&& self) {
  return std::forward_as_tuple(
    std::forward<Self>(self).first,
    std::forward<Self>(self).second
  );
}
```

to the body of your pair.  The enable_if_t stuff is a bit obscure, but it makes sure this free function will only be invoked on genuine xpairs.

Now your operator= is just:

```
xpair& operator= (const xpair& that) {
  tieme(*this)=tieme(that);
  return *this;
}
```

which is nice, because you don't have to repeat the order of your elements twice over.

But it doesn't stop there.

```
friend bool operator<(const xpair& lhs, const xpair& rhs) {
  return tieme(lhs) < tieme(rhs);
}
```

the same technique lets you write a bunch of other operators.  And anyone who has ever had bugs in `<` boilerplate will understand that the above is nice.

Move assign?

```
xpair& operator= (xpair&& that) {
  tieme(*this)=tieme(std::move(that));
  return *this;
}
```

swap?

```
friend void swap(xpair& lhs, xpair& rhs) {
  std::swap( tieme(lhs), tieme(rhs) );
}
```

and it scales -- add more stuff to `tieme`, and it is auto-handled by all your other methods.